# Where to declare a variable (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm making a GUI using Java Swing right now and I'm doing some code refactoring.

My question is this: Does it matter where I declare a variable type in terms of memory/efficiency or anything else for that matter?
Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    JTextField textfield = new JTextField(5);
    // Do stuff with textfield
```

vs:

```
JTextField textfield;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    textfield = new JTextField(5);
    // Do stuff with textfield
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need it inside the loop, declare it inside.
After the loop is finished, the textfield will be available for Garbage Collection.

This way, you make the object available to Garbage Collection as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to create variable only when required. So if you don't require the variable outside the loop then its better to declare and initialize inside the loop only(i.e. the former case mentioned by you)

Answer (score 0):

The first way is safer - if there's some more complex logic to assigning the variable (e.g. in a set of conditions or a switch) and you don't set it in one of the branches, compiler will tell you. With the second approach, such programming error would lead to value from previous iteration to be left in the variable - something that might take long time to even detect.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with all the answers, I believe OP was asking in terms of memory usage/efficiency. Honest, I think it really depends on what kind of work you're trying to do within that for loop. But this can easily be determined through a quick test:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    String textfield1 = "test1";
}
long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
System.out.println("Test 1 time: " + (start - stop) + " millisecond");
System.out.println("Test 1 memory used: " + memory + " bytes");

runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
String textfield2;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    textfield2 = "test2";
}
stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Test 2 time: " + (start - stop) + " millisecond");
System.out.println("Test 2 memory used: " + memory + " bytes");
```

Output:

```
Test 1 time: 0 millisecond
Test 1 memory used: 3963816 bytes
Test 2 time: 0 millisecond
Test 2 memory used: 3963816 bytes
```

Conclusion: For small programs it doesn't matter. If the loop is huge, or if it's a nested loop, then it might make some difference if you're doing some heavy stuff.